# PHP – preg_replace() for words in string (regex pattern difficulties)

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I'm new to PHP & Arrays even though I read a lot of tutorials already. Please be understanding. :)

**My intentions:**
For a fulltext search I'm trying to replace words within a string with custom other words contained in a list of words. It occurs to me that in order to get whole words rather than the found string as part of another word I have to use preg_replace() with a specific pattern instead of str_replace().

**My problem:** If a certain word is part of the list of words i.e. [apples], I'm trying to replace i.e. [Short text in a fulltext search] with i.e. [Short apples in a fulltext search]. Naturally the final string looks like [Short apples in a fullapples search] or I get some delimiter warnings.

So I'm trying to figure out a pattern for the preg_replace() function to only replace full words and not strings within combines words. And on top of that I'm pulling the word pairs out of an associative array to have a better overview of the list. This is where I'm a novice.

**My trials:**

```
$replacements = array(
                  'text' => 'apples',
                  etc…
                );

$pattern = '#\b'($searchterm)'\b#;
$searchterm = preg_replace(array_keys($replacements), $pattern, $searchterm);

echo $searchterm;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You should check the manual on `preg_replace`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Can you give an example of your `$searchterm` ?

Comment: I read the manual but I still can't get my head around it.
@srain: the $searchterm variable just contains a simple string. Probably never more than three different words.

Comment: `strtr` may be enough for this task. In order to replace full words and not strings within combines words, we simply can add blank to the head an to the end of the replace pair. Hope my answer will be helpful. Any other question, feel free to comment here.

Comment: Hey srain, thank you very much for your help and explanation! Seems logic to me now. However I still have problems figuring out how to apply [$from] & [$to] if [$searchterm] is just one single word. I guess because it's looking for a space before the word. Should I solve this with a blunt [if] statement or might there be a more elegant solution?

Comment: (@Whoever it may concern: I'm not really into this voting thing, however it seems strange to me that a question is being downvoted just because it might be nooby. Stackoverflow is a great tool and is here to help, advise and inspire people, no matter how advanced or not they might be.)

Comment: Why `$searchterm` is a single word? You replace from a word to another word, right?

Comment: `$searchterm` must be like `$searchterm = array('a' => 'b')`, right?

Comment: Sometimes the search term to replace in the fulltext search might only be [apples] instead of [green apples on a tree]. Unfortunately since it's searching for spaces, it doesn't replace the first and last word of [$searchterm].

Comment: @Tobias, I think it is not easy to solve this issue by that simple way. So we should turn back to `preg_replace`, I have updated my answer. By the way, do mind that some one gives your a `downvote`. Everyone's opinion is different. I will `upvote` your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtr` may be enough for this task. .

In order to replace full words and not strings within combines words, we simply can add `blank` to the head an to the end of the replace pair.

```
<?php
$replacements = array(
    'text' => 'apples',
);

$realRreplacements = array();
foreach ($replacements as $from => $to)
{
    $from = ' ' . $from . ' ';
    $to = ' ' . $to . ' ';
    $realRreplacements[$from] = $to;
}

$str = 'Short text in a fulltext search';
$str = strtr($str, $realRreplacements);
echo $str, "\n";
// output: Short apples in a fulltext search
```

-

```
                      ************ update *************
```

turn back to `preg_replace`:

```
<?php
$list = array(
    'text' => 'apples',
    'Short' => 'Long',
    'search' => 'find',
);
$pattens = array();
$replacement = array();
foreach ($list as $from => $to)
{
    $from = '/\b' . $from . '\b/';
    $pattens[] = $from;
    $replacement[] = $to;
}
$str = 'Short text in a fulltext search';
$str = preg_replace($pattens, $replacement, $str);
echo $str, "\n"; // Long apples in a fulltext find
```

Comment: Thank you very much srain! After lunch and some tweaks to match the rest of my code, I managed to get it to work like a charm! Definitely taught me something.
And thanks for being so friendly. :)

Comment: I reviewed my comment, I meant `do not mind that some one gives your a downvote`, missed a `not`. ^_^.